# JavaScript Flood Fill RangeError

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm developing a painting application with JavaScript and I need to add a paint bucket tool as well. For this, I did research on the internet and implemented an algorithm I found in my code, but this algorithm revealed an error in my code. When the area to be painted is large, I get `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

My test code:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d', {
    willReadFrequently: true
})
canvas.width = 400
canvas.height = 400

ctx.fillStyle = '#fff'
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

ctx.strokeStyle = '#000'
ctx.lineWidth = 2
ctx.strokeRect(8, 8, canvas.width - 16, canvas.height - 16)

const setColor = (imageData, pixelPos) => {
    imageData.data[pixelPos] = 0
    imageData.data[pixelPos + 1] = 255
    imageData.data[pixelPos + 2] = 0
    imageData.data[pixelPos + 3] = 255
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0)
}

const floodFill = (pixelPos, imageData, oldColor, newColor) => {
    const top = pixelPos - canvas.width * 4
    const bottom = pixelPos + canvas.width * 4
    const left = pixelPos - 4
    const right = pixelPos + 4

    if (
        imageData.data[pixelPos] === oldColor.r &&
        imageData.data[pixelPos + 1] === oldColor.g &&
        imageData.data[pixelPos + 2] === oldColor.b &&
        imageData.data[pixelPos + 3] === oldColor.a
    ) {
        setColor(imageData, pixelPos)
        floodFill(top, imageData, oldColor, newColor)
        floodFill(bottom, imageData, oldColor, newColor)
        floodFill(left, imageData, oldColor, newColor)
        floodFill(right, imageData, oldColor, newColor)
    }
}

addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
        x = Math.floor(e.x - rect.x),
        y = Math.floor(e.y - rect.y)

    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > canvas.width || y > canvas.height) return

    let imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    const pixelPos = (y * canvas.width + x) * 4
    const oldColor = {
        r: imageData.data[pixelPos],
        g: imageData.data[pixelPos + 1],
        b: imageData.data[pixelPos + 2],
        a: imageData.data[pixelPos + 3],
    }
    const newColor = {
        r: 0,
        g: 255,
        b: 0,
        a: 255,
    }

    floodFill(pixelPos, imageData, oldColor, newColor)
})
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Note that regardless of the stack size issue, you absolutely shouldn't put your ImageData on the context at each `setColor`, do it only once, at the end, when all the floodfill has been done on your ImageData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your "flood fill" algorithm is correct in principle, but hopeless in practice

It works on the basis of:

- colour in a pixel
- then go to each of the 4 neighbouring pixels, and call the same function again

The problem with this approach is that an astronomical number of calls are required to complete the flood fill.

Try some other approaches to flood fill:

[which flood-fill algorithm is better for performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318490/which-flood-fill-algorithm-is-better-for-performance)

[What's the best bucket filling algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61195142/whats-the-best-bucket-filling-algorithm)

And review the discussion here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: I replaced the algorithm in my code with a non-recursive algorithm and it works much better now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Browsers have limits, one of them is the stack size, and this is not just an issue on the canvas, any application like yours that uses recursive functions runs the risk of hitting that limit.

One way around is to use `setTimeout`, see sample below:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = canvas.height = 400
ctx.strokeRect(8, 8, 100, 100)
ctx.strokeRect(80, 80, 240, 240)

const setColor = (imageData, pixelPos) => {
  imageData.data[pixelPos] = 0
  imageData.data[pixelPos + 1] = 255
  imageData.data[pixelPos + 2] = 0
  imageData.data[pixelPos + 3] = 255
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0)
}

const checkNear = (pixelPos, imageData, oldColor, newColor) => {
  floodFill(pixelPos - canvas.width * 4, imageData, oldColor, newColor)
  floodFill(pixelPos + canvas.width * 4, imageData, oldColor, newColor)
  floodFill(pixelPos - 4, imageData, oldColor, newColor)
  floodFill(pixelPos + 4, imageData, oldColor, newColor)
}

const floodFill = (pixelPos, imageData, oldColor, newColor) => {
  if (
    imageData.data[pixelPos] === oldColor.r &&
    imageData.data[pixelPos + 1] === oldColor.g &&
    imageData.data[pixelPos + 2] === oldColor.b &&
    imageData.data[pixelPos + 3] === oldColor.a
  ) {
    setColor(imageData, pixelPos)
    setTimeout(() => checkNear(pixelPos, imageData, oldColor, newColor), 1)
  }
}

addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
    x = Math.floor(e.x - rect.x),
    y = Math.floor(e.y - rect.y)

  if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > canvas.width || y > canvas.height) return

  let imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  const pixelPos = (y * canvas.width + x) * 4
  const oldColor = {
    r: imageData.data[pixelPos],
    g: imageData.data[pixelPos + 1],
    b: imageData.data[pixelPos + 2],
    a: imageData.data[pixelPos + 3],
  }
  const newColor = {
    r: 0,
    g: 255,
    b: 0,
    a: 255,
  }

  floodFill(pixelPos, imageData, oldColor, newColor)
})
```

```html
<canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
```

Another option could be using background workers:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

But the answer from [@Eureka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75569248/7599833) is spot on, your algorithm is not very efficient, you should also address that issue to improve overall performance

Comment: Web workers JS engine also have a stack size limit.